# GRPC Java tutorial. Unable to generate source code within one package using protobuf-maven-plugin

Tags: grpc-java

I am new to GRPC, I am following this guide https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/java.html

I have cloned the project from [GITHUB](http://git%20clone%20-b%20v1.10.0%20https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java.git)

And I am trying to build the project by running `mvn clean install`

The build file succeeds: I can see it build all source files, the artifact is being produced and even some integration tests executed.

But when I open the project in Eclipse, I see 3 files in `io.grpc.examples.routeguide` package: `RouteGuideClient`, `RouteGuideServer` and `RouteGuideUtil`. All of them rely on pojos and other helper classes that were supposed to be generated by protobuf/grpc maven plugin.

I can see those files generated under

1. `/target/generated-sources/protobuf/grpc-java/io/grpc/examples/routeguide` : `RouteGuideGrpc.java`
2. `/target/generated-sources/protobuf/java/io/grpc/examples/routeguide` : `FeatureDatabase.java, Feature.java, Point.java, Rectangle.java, RouteGuideProto.java, RouteNoteOrBuilder.java, RouteSummaryOrBuilder.java, FeatureDatabaseOrBuilder.java, FeatureOrBuilder.java, PointOrBuilder.java, RectangleOrBuilder.java, RouteNote.java, RouteSummary.java`

Why those files are not generated in the source code folder `/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/routeguide/`?

I would like to see generated files part of my source code. How can I achieve that? And why there are 2 folders of generated files?

How do I work around this problem so I can work in my IDE without seeing errors?

Comment: Ok, once I have imported a project as a Maven project, Eclipse has identified generated folders as resource folders.
But the problem is that Eclipse still shows some bizarre errors.